# Flexible HTTP paging

Tags: api, rest, http-headers

I'm implementing a pagination through header inside a REST API such as:

> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 32 items by default.
>
> Request can contains a `Range` header to specify further items.
>
> Special cases:
>
> - If the request did not contain a `Range` header, `400 Bad Request` is returned.
> - If the client has asked for a portion of the collection, but the server cannot supply that portion, `416 Requested Range Not
>     Satisfiable` (e.g. when the collection is empty).
> - Otherwise, the server returns the partial collection with `Content-Ranges` header and `206 Partial Content`.
>
> #### Example
>
> Options and/or requirements associated with the collection:
>
> ```
> curl  -u '<email>:<token>' \
>       -H 'Accept: application/json; version=1.0.0' \
>       -X OPTIONS \
>       https://example.com/foos
> ```
>
> Responds with HTTP 200 on success:
>
> - `Accept-Ranges: foos`
> - `Allow: HEAD,GET,OPTIONS`
>
> Get request:
>
> ```
> curl  -u '<email>:<token>' \
>       -H 'Accept: application/json; version=1.0.0' \
>       -H 'Range: foos=100-199' \
>       https://example.com/foos
> ```
>
> Responds with HTTP 206 on success:
>
> ```
> Accept-Ranges: foos
> Content-Range: foos 100-199/1234
> ```

Please, do not hesitate to criticize if you notice anything unusual.  But I am relatively satisfied with this behavior.

However, I also wish it were possible to send a request without explicitly asking 32 items per page. I mean, it should be possible to have by default 32 items per page without specifying any `Range` header... and have 206 in response code from the server. Because I would like to allow client to forget the `Range` header. It would be more simple to use the API.

If it is possible, the following special case can be deleted:

> If the request did not contain a `Range` header, `400 Bad Request` is returned.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the [RFC states](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-25#page-8):

> A proxy MAY discard a Range
> header field that contains a range unit it does not understand.

So when your client is behind a proxy, the `range` header may be dropped.

> However, I also wish it were possible to send a request without explicitly asking 32 items per page. I mean, it should be possible to have by default 32 items per page without specifying any Range header...

That shouldn't be too hard. Psuedo:

```
if (range-header-present)
{
    range = parseRangeFromHeader();
}
else
{
    range = 0-31;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip about the proxy.
But according to your interpretation of this RFC, is it possible to answer from the server to the client a 206 paginated collection after a GET request without any `Range` header from the client to the server?